# How do You exit from an application without exiting the menu that activated the application?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, exit

Bear with me... Im not sure how to ask this question.
I'm working on a Web site using VB.NET and Visual Studios 2017 (soon to upgrade to VS 2019).  The software is activated by a website menu item that I don't have access to; I have no idea how the menu structure calls my software.
The problem the users reported is that my software has a LogOut button that not only closes the application, it also logs them out of the Menu struture.  They would like to exit my software without loggig out of the Menu because restarting the browser and logging back into the menu is a pain (complicated).
I can't show any code because they changed the firewall at work and it blocks this site.

I added a Button to the index screen that says "EXIT".  I figured out that the other buttons activate the javascript section of the Index View.  I tried to find a close, and an exit, and a shutdown, but couldn't find anything that would help.

edit:
I don't have anyway to test this (yet) because I only have access to my personal (work) computer, so I'm not running it from a Menu on a Server, whereas this runs on a Server in Production and is activated by a Menu structure on that server... that I don't yet have access to.
Based on the information from @GrafiCode, I found the HomeController contains:

Response.RedirectPermanent(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BOL.LogoutURL"), false)

I did a trace back to find that there is a web.config file that has the following '' line after the connectionStrings:

```
<add key='"BOL.LogoutUrl" value="https://www.bing.com/"/>
```

and then in the web.config.token file:

```
<add key="BOL.LogoutUrl" value="https://www.__BOLSERVER__/BAM/logout.aspx/"/>
```

My understanding is that the web.config file is replaced by the web.config.token file and the **variable** parts will be replaced with the actual infomation needed for the server environment it is deployed into.
Is it possible that the "logout.aspx" should be something else to keep it from logging out of the Server that contains the Menu that activated my software?  Do you have a suggestion as to what it should be or what I should ask the Server owners about?

Comment: how does your application log the ouser out? One long-shot possibility could be this: your logout routine clears all cookies, including the ones set by the main application, causing it to logout the user too.

Comment: there is a "logout" button on the screen.  The code in the View is this: '[@html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff, "Home") ]  And then in the HOMEController there is a Sub Logoff() immediately followed byt  what looks like a signout function that clears everything that you mentioned.

Comment: there is a line of code in the HomeController that looks like it might be the culprit:  'Response.RedirectPermanent(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BOL.LogoutURL"), false)'